# Error 401 from retrofit even after setting the Authorization Token

Tags: android, authorization, retrofit

Trying to access an api with `@POST` and I already set my `@Header("Authorization") String TOKEN`.

I've tried it with `@GET` and it worked, but I'm passing a some form fields so I need to use `@POST`

```
@POST("details")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Play> playTrack(
        @Header("Authorization") String TOKEN,
        @Field("event_id") int event_id,
        @Field("longitude") double longitude,
        @Field("latitude") double latitude    
);
```

Comment: What is your Authorization token type, is it bearer?

Comment: Error 401 means Unauthorized error. Check whether you are passing correct credentials for authorization

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Yes

Comment: Then don't forgot to add Bearer as prefix to your token. `"Bearer "+ token`

Answer (score 0):

try using Multipart on annotation

```
@Multipart
@POST("details")
Call<ResponseBody> playTrack(
    @Header("Authorization") String token,
    @Part("event_id") RequestBody eventId,
    @Part("longitude") RequestBody longitude,
    @Part("latitude") RequestBody latitude,
);
```

make sure to pass a RequestBody as params

```
val latitude = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), doubleLatitude.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a header interceptor and add it to OkHttpClient :

```
Interceptor headerIntercepter  = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

      return chain.proceed(    chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("authorization- 
client", accessToken).build());

        }
    };

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(headerIntercepter)
            .build();

    try {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Server_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        apiService = retrofit.create(Api.class);
```

Comment: I have tried this. It didn't work. But for my @GET annotation. it worked. so the issue is not the token.

Comment: yeah I know , I mean that u can add the header inside the interceptor like this
    return chain.proceed(    chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", accessToken).build());

Comment: Yes I understand. I even tried that before posting here. Thanks

Comment: Any solution. I am also facing the same

Answer (score 0):

> Seeing a 401 response means that the request was successfully executed
>   and the server returned that status code. This is not a problem with
>   Retrofit, but in whatever authentication information you are including
>   in the request that the server expects.
>
> Try with postman with the same data and check

**N.B: Don't forgot to add *Token Type* as prefix to your token**

Comment: Yes. It was added